# MySQL Declare Continue Handler Syntax error

Tags: mysql, database, error-handling

I am working on a database script for MySQL and I am running into an issue when trying to run the script. The insert statement may throw a foreign key constraint error, which is fine, but I want to handle it by not inserting anything into archivedBooking and not deleting from booking. I then want to continue execution after the last END;

I am getting this error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1452"

```
        BEGIN
            DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR 1452
                BEGIN
                 SELECT 'error, but continue';
                END;

            INSERT INTO archivedBooking
                SELECT BookingId, StartDate, EndDate, StaffId, AvailabilityId 
                FROM booking 
                WHERE EndDate < CURDATE();

            DELETE FROM booking WHERE EndDate < CURDATE();
        END;
```

Comment: i tried your procedure and it shows no errprs on Workbench 8.0.19

Comment: A handler is only allowed inside a stored program (trigger, function, procedure).